# PHP - Parse UTF-8 XML

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I have trouble parse XML (from YouTube) using simple_xml, that have next symbols inside of text node:

```
↓ ‘ ’
```

These symbols was typed in MacOS Safari browser and was saved as video annotations.

XML have encode as UTF8, but if I save file to disk - quotations symbols will be displayed with strange characters code x92, x93 (notepad++, utf8).

if I open this XML in firefox and then save it would read from disk, php parse it w/o problems.
if I directly parse xml from url or using `file_get_contents`, parsing crash.

Also downarrow `↓` charater saved to file as `&#x2193;` - so how to convert back to arrow?

I tried `iconv`, `mb_convert` but nothing helps so far.

Thank you for help, here I attach two XML: first is problem xml (https://www.box.com/s/fgp5rih5s3dgx5y328gh), that I read and save in PHP; the second one I get using download manager program (https://www.box.com/s/fgp5rih5s3dgx5y328gh) or by reading and saving in web-browser (FireFox).

Also I will be deal with data (from others videos) that used chinese, japanese and arabic characters :)))

Comment: Could you give us some of the troublesome XML itself?  Getting the full and exact error messages you're seeing when trying to parse it would also be helpful, as well as the code you're using.  Please edit this into your question.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you see or more details

Comment: here two XML: first is problem xml (https://www.box.com/s/fgp5rih5s3dgx5y328gh), that I read and save in PHP; the second one I get using download manager program (https://www.box.com/s/fgp5rih5s3dgx5y328gh) or by reading and saving in web-browser (FireFox)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just using youtube's xml api from php, the data is already utf-8 and you don't need to do anything complicated, this will work:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%E2%82%ACuro";
$el = simplexml_load_file( $url );
print_r( $el );
```

The only reason that wouldn't have worked for you is if you didn't use a proper charset in the content-type header.

---

Well those quotes are `0x91` and `0x92` (`0x93` is actually `“`) respectively in Windows-1252, so I suspect your file is in Windows-1252.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$str = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
echo html_entity_decode(
       mb_convert_encoding( $str, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252"),
       ENT_QUOTES, 
       "UTF-8"
);
```

Comment: @Ninsuo it was `#x2193;` in his file, ie pure ascii characters `#`, `x`, `2` `1` `9` `3` `;` That's what the `hmtl_entity_decode` is for

Comment: Well the binary values do not match, so it can not be Windows-1252 (which makes somewhat sense with the Mac context given).

Comment: @hakre yes, I have noted that in my answer (Saying that `0x93` is actually `“`). And what Mac Context? Notepad++ is a windows editor.

Comment: *"These symbols was typed in MacOS Safari browser and was saved as video annotations."*

Comment: @hakre yes, they were typed in MacOS, then the browser sent the data as utf-8 to youtube servers when he saved it. Then the OP made API request to youtube to get the annotations back as XML, youtube sent them to him as UTF-8 (very likely), then he saved it to disk in some other encoding other than utf-8 and now he can't read the file.

Comment: thats not how i read the question. the local save to disk is done for trouble-shooting and it fixes the broken file. taking the data directly from youtube does not work. However the original data / URL has not been shown so far but is really important.

Comment: @hakre indeed, there is not much to work with here, I might be totally wrong of course.

Comment: me, too. that's why it's problematic if users posting questions do not react on comments they receive.